# Cakephp - reuse empty ids

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, auto-increment

I need to add in Cakephp records in my table. The amount of these records is very high. Every 2 months, some of these records will be removed from the database. Now my question is, if it is possible later to reuse the ids used before by the removed records, in order to save space?
In the sense that if records with ids from 10 to 40 are removed, then if I want to add a new record, can I reuse these ids from 10 to 40?

Comment: Don't reuse database IDs as that would create inconsistencies. Also, reusing IDs doesn't save space beyond a handful of KB.

Comment: Please don't reuse these id's at it will create a big ambiguity in the system. For an example, if a user saw her/his photo on his dashboard and you are deleting his 3 months older photo, and using that deleted id's again, then when user will open his dashboard he/she will see a  new picture which doesn't belong to him (due to reuse of id this ambiguity arrises)

Answer (score 1):

The data in the table will take up the same amount of space, regardless of what ID the row has, there isn't a blank row or anything left.  I strongly recommend against reusing unique identifiers ... the clue is in the name that they should be unique to each record and not recycled!